# using `update mask` to change ownerId on google classroom class

Tags: api, google-classroom

I am trying to use the google classroom API to change the ownership of a class from one `ownerId` to another in my organisation. What is the code for the `update Mask`field in order to only change the `ownerId` and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal. You must utilize the [Method: courses.patch](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/patch?authuser=1&apix_params=%7B%22id%22%3A%22your-course-id%22%2C%22updateMask%22%3A%22ownerId%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22ownerId%22%3A%22email%40domain%22%7D%7D) endpoint. You can even practice by using the ***Try this API***.

[image]

- `id` refers to the course id.
- `updateMask` refers to the attribute you want to modify.
- `Request body` refers to the data you are going to pass to change it. Ex:

```
{
  "ownerId": "email@domain"
}
```

Then only click ***EXECUTE*** and sign in into your account to be able to interact with the API.

### Notice

- For listing your courses and get their ids. You could use the [Method: courses.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list?authuser=1) endpoint.
- You can only transfer course ownership if the other user is a co-teacher.

### EDIT

> "error": { "code": 400, "message": "@UserInIllegalDomain Invitation
> cannot be created for user in this domain", "status":
> "FAILED_PRECONDITION"

Sorry, the error you are having after deleting a user in your organization who was a course's owner and then tried to change ownership to someone else it's a well-known bug as you can see in these two pages:

- [Failure when adding a teacher to an active course](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-apps-manager/fAuYir7mHHI/-4Q2dkamBAAJ)
- [Deletion of primary teacher from the domain orphans classrooms](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121048526). You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on this page as it lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for this... It really helped, unfortunately I executed the recommended code and it returned the following error:  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "@UserInIllegalDomain Invitation cannot be created for user in this domain",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"      The problem I keep having here is that the current owner Id is of a teacher that no longer exists in our domain... They left the school and their account no longer exists. Do you know whether there is anything else I can do to either update ownership of this class to the coteacher or delete the class?

Answer (score 0):

If the original teacher's account is no longer active as it has been deleted from the domain then there is no way to change the ownership. The only way to change ownership of class is by logging in as the original teacher and changing ownership in Google classroom UI. 
Follow this documentation-
https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/7449476?hl=en

From the APIs you can do it by calling the API with the original teacher's token. But if the original teacher is no longer active then that token will also cease to work. There is a bug logged with Google for a similar issue (not exact same issue) where the original teacher is deleted from the domain-
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146050145

In the mean time the workaround for this scenario is to ask the school domain admin to rejuvenate the original teacher's account from the Google classroom Admin console User Mgmt area. Then impersonate that user by logging in with the account and temp password and carry out the steps as per the documentation to change ownership to new teacher. For workaround steps refer to this comment from google issue tracker for the related bug- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/146050145#comment2

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you rejuvenate a user after it has been deleted for more than 20 days? Alternatively, the class is no longer require, I read online you could delete the orphaned class but that doesn't seem to work either...